# I want to create Spring Legacy Project. But I get the same error

Tags: spring-tool-suite

I install STS3 Add-On to create a spring legacy project in STS4. And I want to create Spring Legacy Project. But whenever I try to create it, I get the same error as in the picture below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uhkyx.png)

My computer enviroment is like this.

1. OS : m1 Mac OS
2. JDK version : 11.0.14.1(Zulu11.54+25-CA)

I have uninstalled and installed STS4 several times, and the JDK version has also been changed from 1.8 to 11.

If anyone knows how to solve it, could you please point it out??

Thank you.XD

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce the issue. It seems to be related to the JDK that is used to run the IDE. The old Spring Tools 3 Add-On Pack fails with this exception when running on a JDK17 (which comes as the default embedded JRE to run the IDE when you download the Spring Tools 4 for Eclipse distribution).

You can fix this by using a JDK11 to run the IDE itself (via modifying the setting in the SpringToolSuite4.ini file). Make sure to remove the existing setting in there that points to the JDK17.

Please note that the Spring Tools 3 Add-On Pack is no longer actively maintained, so the underlying issue will probably not be fixed. If you have something from Spring Tools 3 that is not yet available by default in Spring Tools 4, but you would like to see added, please raise an issue in the Spring Tools 4 issue tracker and provide some background information why that feature should be ported to Spring Tools 4 here: https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues